# android table layout one for both (landscape and portrait view)

Tags: android, tablelayout

I want to create the following layout which should be 100% in landscape form as displaying in portrait form.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b12bb68569.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b12bb68569.png)

here is my code which i tried but not working

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:stretchColumns="0">

<TableRow>
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow>
            <TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TableRow>
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/reviewItemEntityName"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="12345"
                        android:textColor="@color/maroon" />

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/reviewItemStarRating"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/title_1_star" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>



        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/reviewItemDescription"
                android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Description comes here" android:textSize="12sp" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/arrow_nxt"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this is what your looking for, remember to play with the "android:layout_weight" value, it will basically tell the widgets how much they should expand (use the available free space).

have fun.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    >

<TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1">      
        <TableRow>
            <TextView android:text="TextView Up Left" 
                android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </TextView>
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@android:drawable/btn_plus"
                android:gravity="right">
            </ImageView>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="Text view with padding" 
            android:id="@+id/TextView02" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:paddingBottom="20.0dp" 
            android:paddingLeft="20.0dp" 
            android:paddingRight="20.0dp" 
            android:paddingTop="20.0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </TextView>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0">
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView02" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_minus"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            >
        </ImageView>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```